# Cannot change font color with FTGL

Tags: opengl, text, colors, ftgl

How can I change the font color in FTGL?

Comment: More information is necessary... FTGL can render vector fonts, raster fonts (deprecated) or texture fonts. The general idea, however, is that the font is monochrome (it may have shades of grey, but no color) and you will change the color by multiplying it by something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `glColor` call before asking the font to render; you may need to disable lighting depending on your situation.  Here's an example for C++:

```cpp
FTFont *myfont= new FTBufferFont("myfontfile.ttf");

glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glColor4d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
myfont->Render("Hello world");

glPopAttrib();
```

Comment: This is not working. 'glColor4d' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Achilles-96 glColor is a basic opengl function.  You will need to include the opengl header - I doubt that anything else in the code will work without it.  See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColor.xml

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
FTGLPixmapFont font("Myfont.ttf");

glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_BIAS, red - 1);
glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_BIAS, green - 1);
glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_BIAS, blue - 1);

font.Render(str, -1, FTPoint(x, y));

glPopAttrib();
```

You can add another line for `GL_ALPHA_BIAS` if you want your text to be transparent.